# Swift protocol conformity

Tags: swift, class, protocols

I want a variable that conforms to protocol, but the swift compiler tells me the protocol does not confirm.

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {
    var a : A { get }
}
class AA : A {}
// Type 'BB' does not conform to protocol 'B'
class BB : B { 
    let a = AA()
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are not conforming to the protocol because your `a` is not clearly typed as an `A`, but rather inferred as an `AA`. Make it explicit.

```
protocol A {}
protocol B {
    var a : A { get }
}
class AA : A {}

class BB : B {
    let a: A = AA() // Explicitly typed here.
}
```

The fact that you have used `var` in the protocol and `let` in the implementation is a red herring, as the var is a `get` only, and has no `set`.